# Manually calculated field in hibernate POJO

Tags: hibernate, spring, orm

I'm using Spring coupled with Hibernate in my project.

Suppose I've got a `USER` table which is related to `ROLE` through a cross-table and `ROLE` table in turn is related to `PERMISSION` table again through a cross-table. So each user may have several roles and each role may have several permissions which may be shared between different roles. In the orm i will have a User class like this:

```
class User {
    // blah blah properties

    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name="USER_ROLE",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)})
    private Set<Roles> roles;
}
```

now what i want is to have another property in the `User` bean containing a list of permissions of the user as Strings (`List<String> permissions`). the easiest way to do this for me would be if it was possible to call some method of the User object right after it's properties have been populated. The method will do a `for` over the roles and then another one over the permissions and add them to the list of permissions in the user object.

Or maybe hibernate/spring provide something for this exact case?

P.S.
I tried Googling this but was unsuccessful.

Comment: So just add a method to `User` which does this on demand.

Comment: I've done that already but that doesn't feel neat enough for me :) i'm checking in the getter method if the permission list is null and if not i'm populating it. I think there should be a cleaner solution.

Also i'm using a special library which is converting the hibernate managed beans to serializable beans which are being transferred over the network. This lib may, or may not use the getter methods to access the private properties of the bean.

Comment: Is a @PostLoad lifecycle listener what you want? http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/hem/en-US/html/listeners.html

Comment: yeah, exactly what i needed. thanks a lot :) if you post the same as an answer i'll mark it as the correct one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a [@PostLoad callback](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/hem/en-US/html/listeners.html) will help you with this. It allows you to do calculations or modifications right after the entity has been loaded so you can build up the permissions list then.